# Controlar la conexión a internet en una app Flutter

Tags: flutter

Quiero controlar la conexión a internet en una app, para ello tengo a mano [este package](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker?fbclid=IwAR2VxrfVIKoJ8TDHJ3H7WfzqdZQzbQkI88hM7bLYrMYN9xdpND2IESv_thc).

Ahora la pregunta es: ¿como debería implementarlo para que siempre esté activo y apenas el dispositivo móvil se quede sin internet la aplicación deje de funcionar o muestre un cartelito? Cosas así... Los leo, muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 1):

Se puede realizar utilizando Stream, pero sin necesidad de eso creo que para tu caso, es mas fácil usar la dependencia [connection_status_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/connection_status_bar).

Esta dependencia va a animar un widget cuando la connexion a internet cambie.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]